# While loops working mechanism of a program in Scheme

Tags: while-loop, scheme, racket, scoping, mutability

DrRacket user.

I'm struggling to understand how this program works.I wrote it myself and it does what it must but I can't understand how.

I define *while* loops as:

```
(define (while test body)
  (if (test)
      (begin
        (body)
        (while test body))
      (void)))
```

Now I need to write a program that applies the given procedure to each element of a mutable list.

Here what I wrote:

```
(define (mlist-map-while f x)  
  (while (lambda() (not (null? x)))
    (lambda () 
      (set-mcar! x (f (mcar x)))
      (set! x (mcdr x))))
  (void))
```

So, defining

```
 list1 (mlist 1 2 3)
```

and applying

```
(mlist-map-while (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) list1)
```

we get `'(2 3 4)`.

The thing that I don't understand is how the first element of the list stays in it, because if it's done how I wrote here

```
(set! x (mcdr x))
```

the first procedure that sets `-mcar!` must be useless and be overlapped with the second. Like in this example:

```
(define list1 (mlist 1 2 3))
(set-mcar! list1 9)
(set-mcdr! list1 (mcdr list!))
```

and we lack the first element, but this program somehow leaves it in and gives the desired output. I would like to know how it works and whether there is another way of traversing the given list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a big difference between `set-cdr!` abd `set!`. The first alters the pair's `cdr` pointer, while the latter alters the binding, thus what the name should point to.

In your `mlist-map-while` the variable `x` alters the `car`, then changes what `x` *represents*, to be the `cdr` of `x`. It **never** changes the `cdr` so your binding `list1` always points to the first pair while `x` points to the first, then second, etc...

Thus it's more like this:

```
(define list1 (mlist 1 2 3))
(define list1-ref list1)       ; variable pointing to the same value as list1
(set-mcar! list1-ref 9)        ; set-car! changes the pair
(set! list1-ref (mcdr list))   ; set! updates what list1-ref points to
list1    ; ==> (9 2 3)
list-ref ; ==> (2 3)
```

You can iterate over a list in the same fashion without using `set!`, with recursion:

```
(define (fold function init lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      init
      (fold function 
            (function (car lst) init) 
            (cdr lst))))

(fold + 0 '(1 2 3)
; ==> 6

(fold cons '() '(1 2 3))
; ==> (3 2 1)
```

Notice that here we recurse and change what `lst` is, to be the `cdr`. Every recursion has its own `lst`, which is not to be confused with the caller's own. It ends up doing the same as `set!` in your example, without mutation.

Comment: So does it mean that if I define list1-ref as in your example ((set! list1-ref (mcdr list))) the values 2 and 3 still point to the second and the third values of list1? And if I change them the values of list1 will be changed respectively?

Comment: Yes. Because of how a list is modelled each element pair has one element and a link to the rest of the list. `(mlist 1 2 3)` is the same as `(mcons 1 (mcons 2 (mcons 3 '())))`

Comment: Scheme has TCO guarantee though... Just sayin'.

Comment: @WillNess No surprises there and OP's code rely on it, but strangely while ES6 has TCO in its standard, I noticed today that Babel has removed it from its features :-/

Comment: it plays its role in your code for `fold` as well, so technically, there's no "caller's own" `lst` anymore when the recursive call's `lst` replaces it (and so it's in effect a mutation of a binding, implicitly - a.o.t. the explicit mutation of `set!` - but still, a mutation; otherwise, it wouldn't be TCO). but that's an additional complexity for the OP to contend with...

Comment: @WillNess Yes it is a callers own just before.. I like to think of TCO as the callers frame gets cleaned up before the tail call rather than after. For non TCO languages it just always happens after.